# can i get other users informations using facebook GraphApi

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

i want to get other users information such as gender ,age range,location
using their id:
"me?fields=id,name,age_range,gender,location "
can i change that "me" with other users ids and get their public information
any way to do it ?!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-facebook-api/

Comment: No, that is not possible. You’d need their permission to access that kind of data first, meaning they would have to log in to an app you create.